# N-Ary Tree Design with Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, tree, smart-pointers

I'm trying to design a tree class in C++, but I'm running into some trouble with node destruction.

If I destroy a node, I don't want to destroy it's entire sub-tree because there might be something else pointed to it. So the obvious solution is the use reference counting. I'd have a weak pointer to the parent, and a vector of shared pointers to the child nodes. That way if a node is destroyed, it's children are only destroyed if nothing is pointing to them.

But I run into another problem here: adding a child to a node. weak_ptr only works if there's already a shared_ptr pointing to an object. And if I adding a child to a node, I don't know where to find a shared_ptr that's pointing to it. So what do I do here?

Comment: Does every child have a parent?

Comment: Every child has a parent member, but a root wouldn't have a parent.

Comment: I mean logically, not code-wise. Does every child have a member? If so, then in your implementation every child would already live inside the vector of children of its parent, so that's where you can get the shared pointer from. (Though I don't follow 100% why you need shared ownership in the first place...)

Comment: @KerrekSB: While that might be true, it would require that when adding a node you walk two levels up the hierarchy (if the parent node is not the root, that you would have to special case) and then walk the list of children until you find the smart pointer that refers to the node from which you are hanging the new element.

Comment: So, to a get a pointer to a parent, I need to find the pointer in _it's_ parents members? That's an O(n) operation! What about the root?

EDIT: Yeah, what D-Rod said.

Comment: I really only would implement that if there was a compelling use case in my code already. I haven't seen a case where destroying a node but not its subtree would make a lot of sense. What would that mean for the subtree anyway? Would all children become roots?

Comment: @Avi: never mind about the root. Just say something like `auto root = std::make_shared<node>();` and have it managed by a shared pointer, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into `enable_shared_from_this` that allows you to obtain the `shared_ptr` directly from the object. It still requires that the object is managed by a `shared_ptr`, but you don't need to *find* who is holding it.

Comment: Okay, but what about for the root? Wait, I can just have the Tree class hold a shared pointer to the root. We're good!

Comment: @Avi: There are two options: either root is managed by a `shared_ptr` (in which case you are fine), or it is not, in which case you cannot obtain a `weak_ptr` to it. My suggestion would be to also manage the `root` through a `shared_ptr`. In most designs, all nodes are the root of their own subtree, and from that point of view, the root should not be any different than any other node, so if all nodes are managed by `shared_ptr` so should the root node.

Comment: Yeah, I see now how this is probably necessary: When creating new children, you need a `weak_ptr` to the parent, not just a raw pointer, so `shared_from_this` (or `weak_from_this`?) would be necessary.

Comment: @Avi: Note that there could be other alternatives, as for example, passing the `weak_ptr`/`shared_ptr` to the parent to the child's constructor. After all, before inserting it into a given position you have had to locate it... so you already have that information. Passing the parent to the child's constructor is probably a good approach.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on David Rodriguez's idea, a skeleton tree might look like this:

```
struct node : std::enable_shared_from_this<node>
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>> children;
    std::weak_ptr<node> parent;

    void add_child()
    {
        auto n = std::make_shared_node>();
        n->parent = std::weak_ptr<node>(shared_from_this());
        children.emplace_back(n);
    }
}

auto root = std::make_shared<node>();

root.add_child();
root.add_child();
root.add_child();

root.children[0].add_child();
```

(Of course a real-world `node` would have a non-trivial constructor with payload values, and `add_child` would take similar arguments or be a template...)

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you need to consider is the need to have a tree that shares nodes.  I think that sort of thing will be madness, but if you wanted to bring some simplicity to it, consider this:

1. Use a map or vector to actually hold the nodes and manage their lifetime.  You have a map of shared_ptrs and you are good to go.
2. For the tree, separate a child node from the item that it points to.  The idea is that, you use shared_ptrs or even unique pointers on each of the tree nodes themselves. That way, when you free a node, it will do all of the children quite nicely, but, you won't free the potentially duplicate items.
3. Use a weak pointer in the tree node to point to the payload.

Something like this:

```
template <class P> class tree_node {
public:

    std::weak_ptr<tree_node<P>> parent;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<tree_node<P>> children;
    std::weak_ptr<P> data;
};

template <class P> class store {
public:
     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<P>> data;
     tree_node<P> index;
};
```

Something like that.  Some efficiencies for certain cases can be achieved if P is not polymorphic.  But, what you get is a class store, that, automatically frees all of your data structures to make that store, the items, tree, index, and if you delete a node out of data and blow it, calling lock() on the weak pointer to it will let you do something about that.